# Is there some accent pronounces "I'm going to do" as "my do"?

Tags: pronunciation

It sounds like the tutorial is [saying](https://youtu.be/3P49hWpNIzA?t=252)

> put in all your tops. **my do** this all the way down ...

The autogenerated transcript gives

> put in all your tops. **I'm going to do** this all the way down ...

which makes more sense. although I listened over and over again, it does not sound like that.

I would like to know what he exactly saying. Could someone help?

Comment: It sounds like that to me too. The speaker has a Southern US accent. I'll leave it to Americans to supply further details.

Comment: In *very* relaxed speech (and sterotypically from speakers with an *Italian* background), you'll hear ***I'm-a do** this all the way down* (or ***I'm gə** do,* reduced forms of ***I am going to do...***), but I can't imagine any context for any dialectal speaker where it might be heard as ***My do** this...*

Comment: This guy is dragging himself and his nail gun back and forth over this wall frame. It is not surprising if he mispronounces a few words.

Comment: I hear, "I'm a-gonna do this..." or "I'm gonna do this..." with gonna pronounced like gun-uh. Sorry, I don't know IPA notation.